# How to save an image uploaded from Quill toolbox

Tags: jquery, quill

Saving an image uploaded from Quill toolbox along with the description .

Answer (score 0):

> Saving an image uploaded from Quill toolbox along with the description
>   .

"toolbox"? Do you mean the toolbar? If the image is already appearing in the editor, then it is already in Delta, which represents the existing Quill data. All you have to do is just get and save the Delta. To get the existing content inside the editor, see the following link:

[How do I retrieve the contents of a Quill text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541353/how-do-i-retrieve-the-contents-of-a-quill-text-editor/42541886#42541886)

For more information, see:

[Quill-Examples-and-FAQ](https://github.com/loagit/Quill-Examples-and-FAQ)